Sojourn time approximation for priority queues
For $M/M/c$ queues (number of servers $c\ge 1$) with two classes of customers and non-preemptive priorities, I know a few sources deriving the Laplace or Laplace-Stieltjes transform of the waiting time distribution. Are there good approximations for the sojourn time distribution? I am looking for a more tractable estimate of the probability.
